# What is the next term in the jumping champions?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, groups-enumeration

I am interested in the jumping champions of the number of groups of order $n$, where $n$ is cubefree.

After calling

```
LoadPackage("cubefree");
```

GAP gives the following jumping champions :

```
gap> maxi:=0; for n in [1..50000] do if IsCubeFreeInt(n)=true then s:=NrSmallGroups(n); if s>maxi then maxi:=s;Print(n,":",s,"\n"); fi;fi;od;
0
1:1
4:2
12:5
36:14
84:15
100:16
156:18
180:37
252:46
300:49
468:55
588:66
882:68
900:150
1764:228
3276:268
6084:298
6300:570
8820:672
11700:732
14700:771
16380:857
22932:1632
42588:1920
44100:3093
gap>
```

What is the next ?

I used `NumberCFGroups` from the [Cubefree package](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/cubefree.html) and restarted the jumping champions and got :

```
gap> maxi:=0; for n in [50000..10^5] do if IsCubeFreeInt(n)=true then u:=NumberCFGroups(n); if u>maxi then maxi:=u; Print(n,":",u,"\n"); fi;fi;od;
0
50001:3
50002:4
50007:5
50010:8
50020:141
50148:259
50700:1154
54684:1417
62244:2270
```

So, the next champion must be greater than $62,244$.

> Can anyone extend the table ?

Comment: Exactly what is a jumping champion?

Comment: It is the next natural number $n$ (together with $f(n)$) , such that the value of $f(n)$ beats the current maximum of $f(n)$. The name jumping champions is quite common in number theory. (For example : the prime gaps)

Comment: In short, I need the smallest cubefree number $n$ with $gnu(n)>3093$, then the smallest cubefree number, such that $gnu(n)$ beats the new record and so on.

Comment: The next champion is at most $81900$ because of $gnu(81900)=4087$

Comment: I suggest to submit 1,4,12,36,84,100,156,180 etc. to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) so that new entries could be added there.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov The goal of this question is to approve my conjecture, that $gnu(n)<n$ holds for all cubefree inetegers $n>1$. In fact, I conjecture $gnu(n)<n$ for all biquadratfree integers $n>1$ (Integers $n$, such that there is no prime $p$ with $p^4|n$).

Comment: I asked for a proof of $gnu(n)<n$ for all cubefree $n>1$, but apparently, the problem is currently open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've calculated this for $1 \le n \le 10^5$ using `ParListWithSCSCP` (see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/scscp/doc/chap8.html#X788208B57D4C497F)) with one master and $48$ workers. This is an embarrassingly parallel calculation, and it took about half an hour on a 64-core Linux server with AMD Opteron 6375 1400MHz CPUs. It confirms that the next entry is given by $gnu(81900)=4087$, and there is no further champion for $81900 < n \le 100000$.

I have a simple example of using SCSCP package for parallel search in the small group library at https://github.com/olexandr-konovalov/scscp-demo. Please remember that you should take care of load-balancing: for too short tasks, parallel calculation will most likely be slower than sequential, and the definition of "too short" depends on several factors, including the number of workers.

Comment: Thank you for your calculation. I also got $81,900$ to be the next champion, but did not continue further. I accepted your answer, but you are, of course, invitied to continue the search.